# Android:Is this possible to generate the view's Bitmap

Tags: android, view

I have 4 layouts(views) and I wanna get their shortcuts.
I use "`getDrawingCache()`",yeah,I get the pictures,but I found if I wanna get the pictures,I had to make them shown.(**I mean they have to be displayed to the user**).
So **Is there any way to get their pictures without displaying them??**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will guide you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604125/android-taking-screenshot-of-offscreen-page

Comment: @blessenm Thanks.But I got errors when I added the code:"measure(...)".I donnot know Why?Is it impossible to get its sreenshortcut if the view is not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

window.getDecorView().buildDrawingCache();
window.getDecorView().getDrawingCache();
```

This is what is done to update activities in tab activity. Im not sure but its worth a try.

Comment: Thanks.But I got errors when I added the code:"measure(...)".I donnot know Why?Is it impossible to get its sreenshortcut if the view is not visible?

Comment: Well you cannot get the drawing cache without actually drawing on the screen. The method we did in the other post i mentioned is that we are accessing the drawing cache before the screen is shown on the screen. But using that method there still a small flicker. btw there is measure... in the code.

Comment: So If I have 4 LinearLayouts which are inflated from xml file.If I dont  draw them on the screen,I get nothing by using getDrawingCache() method,YES?You mentioned the other post is which?Thx

Comment: Yes. and the post i mentioned is the one I added as comment to ur question.

Comment: Btw you might want to try this post. http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/30676.aspx. They use method by passing a bitmap to the view's dispatchDraw method.