# Take screenshot programatically for Google map V2

Tags: android, screenshot, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing one **Track Routes** application for *bikers*. SO whatever route was drawn on map, I want that screen shot with that path drawn to use in share with Social Media.

But I am not getting screen shot of the map.

Anyone know how to take screen shot of the `Google Map V2`.

Comment: This looks like what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762643/android-take-screen-shot-programatically

Comment: Ya code is fine but its not what I need is, I need Google map V2 things. Thanks for reply but its not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method called `getDrawingCache()` provided by every view. You can try following code.

```
MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
map.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = map.getDrawingCache();
map.destroyDrawingCache();
```

You have now `bitmap`. You can use it as you want.

Comment: Yeah you are right but not for Google Map api V2. Because this api is using fragment to display the map not the view. So I am not getting the view of the map. Sorry but this will not work for map api v2.

Comment: @pratik, But in MapFragment, aren't you getting any MapView inside?

Comment: No I have tried a lot but unable to get it. Most of the sites are saying that its not possible in map api V2 because it is using OpenGL to display the map.

Comment: @pratik, Okay. I haven't tried in map, but I got those method in MapViews. Let me try that and let you know.