# Take a screenshot android (continue)

Tags: android, image, caching, screenshot

first of all sorry.. but i cant answer in
[Android take screen shot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762643/android-take-screen-shot-programatically) cause dont have enought reputation.

The code works fine! thanks.. but.. when i take the screenshot.. the file is stored in the root folder

```
String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myPath = new File(extr, getString(R.string.tituloAplicacion)+".jpg");
```

but also appears in the Camera DCM folder with another name, its possible avoid that?

Thanks

Comment: hide the file, see if that works.

Comment: Why do you want to answer !!! :)

Comment: ups..I am sorry the answer I wanted to add was that question: (
no way to avoid generating the file in the folder of the camera DCM? Why is generated there?

twntee  hide the file on the SD or the DCM folder? how do i make that?

Comment: well i try put a "." before the name of the file.. the problem is that in the moment of take the screenshot with that code the file not appears in the gallery, but when i reboot the phone or execute SDRESCAN, in the phone appears my file in SD and the file with another name in the DCM folder Camera :/.  The file in the SD it will be delete after send it to email, but the other..

Comment: i found it :) use: "MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(null, b, "Screen", "screen");" without getContentResolver() and the thumbnail not its created in the DCM folder. Hope this help anybody.

Comment: i found it 2.0 :)  change the getcontentresolver for null.. make a error in the logcat "Failed to insert image".  finally.. delete the line MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage and it works as i need it. Dont know exactly which is used MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage