# why screenshots have low quality?

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm taking screenshot of my Layout with this code:

```
View u = findViewById(R.id.mainL);
u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);                                                
LinearLayout z = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainL);
int totalHeight = z.getHeight();
int totalWidth = z.getWidth();
u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);    
u.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());             
u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

obviously I'm not doing anything on quality but the result bitmap (that is a jpeg image) has a very bad quality.

what am I doing wrong?
I thing I should change it to a PNG Image somehow for better quality but I don't know how.
thanks.

**Edit:**

for those who ask where am I saving the bitmap I have to say that I'm not saving it at all. I just share it with this code:

```
        String pathofBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b , "title", null);
        Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
```

Comment: "what am I doing wrong?" -- if nothing else, you are not showing the code where you are saving the JPEG file. "I thing I should change it to a PNG Image somehow for better quality but I don't know how" -- since you have not supplied the code where you are saving the JPEG file, we have no way of suggesting how you might change that code to save a PNG file instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to say that I'm not saving it at all

Yes, you are. Otherwise, you would not have `pathofBmp`. Now, in your case, you are delegating everything about saving the bitmap to the `MediaStore`. I have never used `insertImage()` and I have no idea what it does in terms of file formats, quality percentage, etc.

If you want more control over saving the image, [use `compress()` on `Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) to write it to a file yourself.

Comment: by save I meant that the image won't be usable through Gallery outside the app. But Yes, I have to use that command. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
View v = view.getRootView();
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myPath = new File(extr, getString(R.string.free_tiket)+".jpg");
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think problem is compress 100 is fix your problem.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762643/android-take-screen-shot-programatically)

Comment: your answer is doing my work in a completely another way. I just want to create a bitmap for sharing purposes not saving.

Comment: can u try this **b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);**