# How to take a scrolling screenshot of a Fragment in Android using View.MeasureSpec?

Tags: android, android-fragments, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot programmatically of a Fragment. The screenshot must include even the portion that is yet to be seen by the user, i.e. the unscrolled portion of the activity.

**Method 1**

I have referred to [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650497/how-to-take-screenshot-of-whole-activity-page-programmatically) and implemented this code:

```
public boolean takeScreenShot() {
    Bitmap bitmap = getScreenBitmap();
    return saveBitmap(bitmap); // function to save the screenshot as a JPEG on the device
}

public Bitmap getScreenBitmap() {
    if (mFragment == null) return null; //mFragment is the Fragment whose screenshot I need
    View v = mFragment.getView(); //getView returns the rootView of the Fragment
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    /*The line causing trouble: v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));*/
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    v.draw(c);
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

If I execute the above code with the `v.measure()` line commented, I get a regular screenshot (excluding the yet-to-be-scrolled portion).

If I remove the comment and execute, the app crashes and I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:810)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:789)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:756)
    at com.company.mypackage.custom.MyTestActivity.getScreenBitmap(MyTestActivity.java:180)
```

**Method 2**

If I replace the `createBitmap` line in the above code snippet with

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
```

I get a `NullPointerException` at this line because `v.getDrawingCache()` returns null.

**Method 3**

I have tried [PGSSoft's scrollscreenshot tool](https://github.com/PGSSoft/scrollscreenshot) and executed this command after downloading the necessary packages (I have checked that the device number for my emulator is 5, and that I am executing it in the correct directory)

```
java -cp scrollscreenshot-latest.jar com.pgssoft.scrollscreenshot.ScrollScreenShot -i 5
```

This gives me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.pgssoft.scrollscreenshot.ScrollScreenShot
```

Could anyone guide me as to how to proceed?

Comment: If not a direct answer, could anyone tell me whether this is even possible, or if I'm trying something futile?