# how to take screenshot of whole windows screen not just the part that is visible

Tags: java, screenshot, java-io, hexdump, hex-editors

I know there is this question on Stack Overflow that answers how to do this in Android [Android solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650497/how-to-take-screenshot-of-whole-activity-page-programmatically), and another question on stack overflow that asks and answers how to take a screeshot of the whole webpage at once even the part that are not visible [Web browser solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090464/how-to-take-screenshot-of-whole-web-page-rather-than-what-shows-on-the-screen)

Now my question is i am bulding an hex editor and i want to take a full screenshot of the whole window when i open a file AND NOT JUST THE PART THAT IS CURRENTLY VISIBLE. How do i do this in Java preferably.

[Currently, i can get screenshots of only part of file currently visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys0So.png)

Whereas, i want the picture to take a picture of every part of the file and not just the part that is currently visible.

By the way the picture up the is using a free hex editor i downloaded online.

Comment: Possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image

Comment: Not really possible. Any editor with variably sized content will use a scroll pane, displaying only as much as fits into the window. While you *could* possibly make the window larger to show more of the file, you will run into memory issues quickly. Rendering HEX is dead simple, so why not simply do it yourself?

Comment: Isn't that the same way taking screenshots in chrome work? Chrome also uses a scroll for webpages that are longer. It seems that the webpage is already fully loaded into memory. So you can take a screenshot of the whole webpage in chrome even if only a small portion is currently showing. By rendering HEX, pls what do you mean?

Comment: The difference between taking a cap of a scrollpane from *within* the program containing the scrollpane and taking a cap from *another* program containing *a* scrollpane is simply that you have *no way* of getting a handle on said scrollpane - making this an impractical approach. By "rendering HEX" I mean paint an image containing what you want *from your program* instead of attempting to fiddle around with *another* program.