# Take screenshot of an activity on click in android

Tags: android

I want to take screenshot of an activity and show it in next activity on button click.
I'm using following code but its not working.

Please let me know if anyone knows the answer:

```
choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mainlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    mainlayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                    mainlayout.layout(0, 0, mainlayout.getMeasuredWidth(), mainlayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                    mainlayout.buildDrawingCache(true);
                    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainlayout.getDrawingCache());
                    mainlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
                    Intent i4=new Intent(Screen3.this,Screen4.class);
                    i4.putExtra("BitmapImage", b);
                    startActivity(i4);
                }//onclick
            });
```

Comment: "its not working" -> can you explain further what is not working ?

Comment: How do you get it in your `Screen4` activity?

Comment: I want to take a screenshot of current activity and show it in next by intent. but code not works..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762643/android-take-screen-shot-programatically

Comment: im using this code in Screen4:   public class Screen4 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen4);
        ImageView cropimage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cropimage);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bitmap b = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
        BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(b);
        cropimage.setImageDrawable(background);

    }

Comment: Do you want to do the screenshoot when a button is clicked?

Comment: @Skizo That is what the above code is saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap captureScreen(View v){

        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            if(v!=null)
            {
                 int width = v.getWidth();
                 int height = v.getHeight();

                 Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                 v.draw(new Canvas(screenshot));
                }
             } 
        catch (Exception e){

             Log.d("captureScreen", "Failed");
        }

     return bitmap;
     }
```

v is the what is being capturing (any layout)

Comment: can v be an imageview? or it must be any layout??

Comment: and how i show this screenshot in next activity's imageview ?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("bmp", bitmap);

and in second activity 

Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("bmp");