# Page curl effect in an Activity in android

Tags: android, animation

Hi i'm a new t android and its animations.

I am developing a android app where in i need to make a book for the text and have to give a curl effect to the books page. I have seen may page curl examples on the internet till now. But they all have the images on them and a curl effect is given to them.

I wanted to ask whether it is possible to have a curl effect given to activity in android or not? As i have text to be written on the activity as well as other features like bookmark and search.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl Page Curl for Android without OpenGL ES

Comment: I have also tried harism bolg for page curl but all are on images none on an activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [code.google.com/p/android-page-curl](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl) and take screenshot of the activity before doing it like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604125/android-taking-screenshot-of-offscreen-page). After that just use page-curl with obtained images.