# programmatically take bitmap screenshot Android

Tags: java, android, screenshot

Is it possible to programmatically take a screenshot of an activity that is currently not displayed? Maybe using findViewById()?

I would want my app to take a screenshot of another activity after a button press in the current activity.

Why won't something like this work?

```
    Bitmap screen; View v1 = findViewById(R.id.someView);
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    screen = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I not am sure you searched the Stackoverflow for similar questions, never mind, see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212385/380161

Comment: I would want my app to take a screenshot of another activity after a button press in the current activity.....could you elaborate more on that..did'nt quite get what you want to achieve here

Comment: Sorry, that was poorly worded. Let's say I have activity1 and it has a button that says "take screenshot". I also have activity2 in my app that has some content (like graphs). My goal is when the user presses the screenshot button in activity1, the application takes a screenshot of activity2. I don't know if this is even possible and that's why I asked :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604125/android-taking-screenshot-of-offscreen-page could be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would want my app to take a screenshot of another activity after a button press in the current activity.

If the other `Activity` is running in the background, you can convert the `View` into `Bitmap` by notifying it via LocalBroadcast events. cheers :)

Comment: So it is possible! Thanks!

Comment: @Darish The activity who's screenshot is to be taken has to be started first else the screenshot would not be taken right?